# Inappropriate user images

Tags: discussion, policy, user-accounts, modesty-policy

What is MY's official policy regarding inappropriate images (such as pornography, gruesome/violent imagery) not just in the content of the question, but as the user photo (other potential examples: a swastika; an immodestly dressed person; etc.)?

Comment: If you are making reference to a particular user photo from today, I actually did a Google Image search to see if it was a stock photo (which I would have suggested to change) but it wasn't. I therefore assumed it was really that particular person and, even if the pic doesn't match our *tzniut* standards, I felt it would be "too much" to ask that person to change it esp. since that user had been a longtime user of other SE sites. One man's opinion of course

Answer (score 8):

A profile is the user's space to use, *within reason*.  There are limits, as described in [this Meta.SE post from a leader of the community team at SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/162102):

> **We will probably not allow:**
>
> - Most terms or statements that directly malign (non-famous) individuals
> - Any terms or statements that imply something derogatory about a racial, ethnic, religious, gender or sexual orientation group
> - Things that are likely to be strong emotional triggers (like rape, suicide, etc.)
> - Statements that appear to be demonstrably libelous
>
> **We will probably allow:**
>
> - Things groups or individuals would vehemently disagree with, but don't seem to directly malign them.

Moderators have reset profile images and removed profile content that violates these norms, including pornography, graphic violence, personal attacks, and Nazi symbolism.  Immodesty (that is not pornographic) is a gray area that we would need to discuss more; while it is probably on the "allow" side of the line on the network at large, a community where that is a *particular* concern, stronger than in the population at large, might reasonably restrict it.  I think we'll need to evaluate cases individually until we build up some "case law", so to speak.

If you see something problematic, please flag one of the user's posts and explain the problem.  (You can't flag users directly.)  Please then check your flag responses; if it's a gray area we might leave it alone for now and ask you to raise the issue on meta (not to call out an individual user but to try to refine the boundaries).  Your flag responses are linked on your profile, in the same box that reports edits, votes, and the number of people you've reached.